# Why color in button not same as example from website

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am building a web site with Bootstrap. I've noticed that the color of the various buttons on my website are paler than those on bootstrap's website.

**An example from website.**
[image]

**On my website.**

[image]

What is different?

Answer (score 0):

OK. I got an answer.

in `resources\assets\sass\_variables.scss`. They have

Just change

```
// Brands
$brand-primary: #3097D1;
$brand-info: #8eb4cb;
$brand-success: #2ab27b;
$brand-warning: #cbb956;
$brand-danger: #bf5329;
```

To this.

```
// Brands
$brand-primary: #337ab7;
$brand-info: #5bc0de;
$brand-success: #5cb85c;
$brand-warning: #ec971f;
$brand-danger: #d9534f;
```